# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (error occured when using squares which is defined in another function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I am trying to make board of chess game using square components where I have initialized another function to put ImageIcon  and pieces in the board the problem is

> TypeError:Cannot read property '0' of undefined

this error occurs whenever I try to use the squares I have returned in the helper function

```
class Board extends Component {
  renderSquare(i, squareShade) {
    const squares = initialiseChessBoard();
    //for (let i = 0; i <= squares.length; i++) {
    console.log(squares);

    console.log(i);
    // console.log("Consoling squares" + this.squares[i]);
    const m1 = (
      <Square
        piece={this.squares[i]}
        style={this.squares[i] ? this.squares[i].style : null}
        shade={squareShade}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
      />
    );
    return <h1>{m1}</h1>;
  }

  render() {
    console.log(initialiseChessBoard());
    function isEven(num) {
      return num % 2 === 0;
    }
    const board = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      const squareRows = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        const squareShade =
          (isEven(i) && isEven(j)) || (!isEven(i) && !isEven(j))
            ? "light-square"
            : "dark-square";
        squareRows.push(this.renderSquare(i * 8 + j, squareShade));
      }
      board.push(<div className="board-row">{squareRows}</div>);
    }

    return <div>{board}</div>;
  }
}

export default Board;
```

Comment: In renderSquare function you are trying to access this.squares you should try to access squares.

Answer (score 1):

The class Board doesn't have the member named `squares`, so the `this.squares` will be undefined. But the function `renderSquare` has an internal variable you'd declared as `const squares`. You can access the variable like `squares[i]` without this keyword.